# Filter menu with items varying according to the value of a variable

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-menu

I am developing an application whose purpose is to display some content from a database in a listview according to the button clicked. It works this way : I have a main activity with 9 different buttons (for example: "Restaurants" "Fast Food" "Coffee Shop" etc), every time the user clicks on one of these buttons, it opens one same activity (called ResultListViewActivity) but with different contents every time (list of restaurants, fast food, etc).
So there is one and only one activity to display the content but the content of the listview itself varies according to the button clicked.

Now this works, I want to add a filter menu in my ResultListViewActivity to add more options for the user. The problem is, this menu should be different according to the button clicked. For example, if the user clicks "Restaurants" in the Main Activity, it should open the ResultListViewActivity with a menu featuring items like "Asian Cuisine", "French Cuisine", etc., but if he clicks on Coffee Shops, it would be "Tea House" "Café", etc. with specific method for each item.

Here is my idea to organize this code :
[image]

The idea is to have a variable called myVariable whose value is set anytime a button is clicked (ex: you click button1, myVariable=1), to send this variable to my ResultListViewActivity, and then to write 9 situations with "if" sentences.
In each of these situations, I would add items to my menu and define what these item are supposed to do.

My question is : I think this should work but I also know there might be something more direct or light to do to avoid writing 9 situations. I am willing to write my code the way it's explained above but I am worried my beginner level in android keeps me from knowing some more efficient way to do it.

ps : to access items I would probably use a submenu called "Filters" from my action bar or a spinner if it isn't possible (I already have one action bar at the bottom of my screen, not sure I can have another one on top).

Comment: Do you mean menu as in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Actually not necessarily I guess, it could as well be a spinner or whatever doesn't take too much space and can display a longer list of item by clicking on it. Though ideally it might be better to use onCreateOptionsMenu but as I am already using an action bar which remains the same on my complete application, I don't know if I can use this again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 9 different menus and inflate one appropriate to myVariable. Say myVariable is an integer then

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    switch (myVariable)
    {
        case 1: 
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_restaurant, menu);
            break;

        case 2:
            ........

        .....
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried and it gives me encouraging results! I can display different lists of menu according to the button clicked. Do you know if it is possible to get access to this menu with an icon on top of the screen with a popup menu instead of what it is now (click on the menu button of the phone) ?

Comment: Why does it not appear on the action bar if your app target sdk >= 11? Do you want it on the action bar?

Comment: I want it on the action bar but on the top of my screen. With an icon on the upper right corner called "Filter" which open a popup menu with the content defined above when I click on it. So far, I think it's on the "menu button" because by default it goes there. If there was no such button on my device, I think it would go to the action bar.